# How to randomly choose a list out of 4 lists?

Tags: python, random

I have 3 lists, every time I want randomly pick any of the items. How can I do that?

```
fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
transport_list = ['car', 'bus', 'ship']
animal_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'Tiger']
```

Comment: The question title is about randomly choosing a list out of 4 lists, but your question states about randomly picking the *items* inside the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `random.choice()`

Add your lists together and samples from the combined lists:

```
import random

fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
transport_list = ['car', 'bus', 'ship']
animal_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'Tiger']

l = fruit_list + transport_list + animal_list

print(random.choice(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to randomly choose items from a list, do this:

```
import random

fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
transport_list = ['car', 'bus', 'ship']
animal_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'Tiger']

fruit = random.choice(fruit_list)
transport = random.choice(transport_list)
animal = random.choice(animal_list)
```

using the `random` library.

---

If you want to choose an item out of any of the three lists, you add them together, then use `random.choice()`. Another way to do it is to use

```
import random

fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
transport_list = ['car', 'bus', 'ship']
animal_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'Tiger']

fruit = random.choice(fruit_list)
transport = random.choice(transport_list)
animal = random.choice(animal_list)

random_list = [fruit, transport, animal]
random_item = random.choice(random_list)
```

Comment: I know that, What i need is , one item out of 3 lists. I found a way that,  i have created another list from 3 lists, then again i run random function to get a final item. is there any ther ways to do that ?

Comment: @PythonPitch add another comment instead of editing the original

Comment: When i use your syntax, getting below error
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @PythonPitch nevermind, add them together is fine. also you can accept my answer by clicking the gray checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module in python named random. You can google it up, but here is how you pick random elements from a list.

```
import random
fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
random.choice(fruit_list)
```

this will pick a random element from fruit_list
If you instead want to pick a random list out of those three, then you can put the lists in a list like this:-

```
import random
fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
transport_list = ['car', 'bus', 'ship']
animal_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'Tiger']
random.choice(fruit_list, transport_list, animal_list)
```